# Changing image src & href path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change multiple images path but there is something wrong whit this. can anyone help me to figure it out pls. The code is working well but all the thumbnail images and the href path appears in the same image source (01_sml.jpg) & (Picture1.jpg).

js --

```
$img = $('#adv1 li img');
    $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/") );
    $img = $('#adv1 li a');
    $img.attr('href', $img.attr('href').replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/") );
```

html --

```
<ul class="thumbs" id="adv1">
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture1.jpg"><img src="img/01_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture2.jpg"><img src="img/02_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture3a.jpg"><img src="img/03_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture4.jpg"><img src="img/04_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture5.jpg"><img src="img/05_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture6.jpg"><img src="img/06_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture7.jpg"><img src="img/07_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="img/Picture8.jpg"><img src="img/08_sml.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? The jQuery you posted does change all the `src` and `href` attributes to the same thing.

Comment: I just want to change the href and src 's image paths > img/ to img/_advertorial/00/ thats all.

Comment: Using latest jQuery 2.1.1, that's what happens: your code works!

Comment: just want to replace the image path folder, not to replace or duplicate filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.each` to go over each element so you don't overwrite all of them:

```
$img = $('#adv1 li img');
$img.each(function( i ) {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/") );
});

$img = $('#adv1 li a');
$img.each(function( i ) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/") );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$img=$('#adv1 li img') returns array of img elements so you need to iterate over then using .each() function

```
    $img = $('#adv1 li img');
$img.each(function( i ) {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/") );
});

$img = $('#adv1 li a');
$img.each(function( i ) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/") );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function overload of [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) to execute an action for each element and assign it's value:

```
$('#adv1 li img').prop("src", function(index, existingValue) {
    return existingValue.replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/");
}); 
$('#adv1 li a').prop("href", function(index, existingValue) {
    return existingValue.replace("img/","img/_advertorial/00/");
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/238er6km/)

The advantage to this is that you're not re-querying for information that jQuery already provides, like the existing value of the property.